# what would be the correct representation of categorical variables like sex?

Tags: feature-selection, dummy-variables

I have a doubt about what will be the right way to use or represent categorical variables with only two values like "sex". I have checked it up from different sources, but I was not able to find any solid reference. For example, if I have the variable sex I usually see this in this form:

id sex
1  male
2  female
3  female
4  male

So I found that one can use dummy variables like this:
[image]

(https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/easy-methods-deal-categorical-variables-predictive-modeling/)

and also in this way:

[image]

(https://stattrek.com/multiple-regression/dummy-variables.aspx)

Therefore, which one would be more adequate way to deal with this variable, for example,  in a classification system. I am inclined to go with the dummy variables, but I would like some opinion about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case can be simplified with a single boolean feature because the original variable `sex` is binary: it can only have values male or female.

This implies that the two values are complementary of each other, so there is no need to keep both: $X_1$ contains exactly as much information as keeping both `sex_male` and `sex_female`.

Note that this simplification cannot be done as soon as the categorical variable can have more than two values.

Side note: sex is not always a binary variable anymore, many surveys would propose a third options such as "doesn't identify as binary".

Comment: thank you for your reply, please could you expand your last part in which you mention the third option?

Comment: @Lila this is a recent social change, it's not related to data science: surveys often give several choices, for example 'non binary' additionally to male and female. For example the [SO survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/) asks about gender with many choices: man, woman, "gender queer or gender non-conforming", "non-binary".

Answer (score -1):

There are three encoding options you can utilise for your scenario of sex(gender)

1. ***One hot Encoding***: Here each category is mapped to binary variable containing either 0 or 1.Widely utilized when features are nominal.
2. ***Dummy Encoding***: similar to one hot encoding. While one hot encoding utilises N binary variables for N categories in a variable. Dummy encoding uses N-1 features to represent N labels/categories
3. ***Effect Encoding***: Also known as *deviation encoding* or *sum encoding*. Similar to dummy encoding, however 3 values are used(1,0,-1)

Do look into [Encoding Categorical Variables](https://medium.com/wicds/label-and-one-hot-encoding-61525a32b99c)

Do note that [gender identity](https://teentalk.ca/learn-about/gender-identity/) is not always binary(0 or 1)

> There are many different gender identities, including male, female, transgender, gender neutral, non-binary, agender, pangender, genderqueer, two-spirit, third gender, and all, none or a combination of these.

Comment: Some of the text looks similar to https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/08/types-of-categorical-data-encoding/: "Here each category is mapped to binary variable containing either 0 or 1" vs "Each category is mapped with a binary variable containing either 0 or 1."; "Dummy encoding uses N-1 features to represent N labels/categories."  Please make sure to provide proper attribution for your sources.